# Include corresponding data from table to json from another table

Tags: php

I have two tables-food and tags. Each row from food has corresponding tags.
I want to output each row with those tags, ie:

### table food:

#### id | name

1  | bread

2  | meat

### table tags:

#### reference_id | tag

1            | bakery

1            | wheat

2            | cow

#### desired output is:

{"results":
[{"id":"1","name":"bread","tags":["bakery","wheat"]},

{"id":"2","name":"meat","tags":["cow"]}]
}

So far I have this:

```
$db = getConnection();
$stmt = $db->query($sql);//get every column from every food  
$food = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$tagsSql="select id_reference,tag FROM tags T,food F WHERE F.id=T.food_id_reference";
$stmt = $db->query($tagsSql);  
$tags=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
echo '{"results":' . json_encode($food) . '}';
```

I was thinking about cycling through every food and ever tag and find matching pairs, but it seems pretty heavyweight to me (considering the fact, that I could have thousands of rows). Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested but I think something like this should work for you

```
$db = getConnection();
$stmt = $db->query($sql);//get every column from every food  
$tagsSql="select F.id as id, F.name as name, group_concat(T.tag SEPARATOR ',') as tags FROM tags T,feeds F WHERE F.id=T.feed_id_reference group by feed_id_reference";
$stmt = $db->query($tagsSql);  
for($x = 0; $x < count($tags); $x++){
    $tags[$x]->{"tags"} = explode(",", $tags[$x]->{"tags"});
    echo '{"results":' . json_encode($tags) . '}';
}
```

Comment: thank you, it needed some minor corrections, but it did the trick

Comment: let me know the corrects and I will update the answer to help the next guy

Comment: I edited your answer + to view ALL food entries from table, it is neccessary that every food has its related tags table (otherwise the result in $tags would be only food rows which has some tags)